# Firebase scheduled cloud function not deleting nodes

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've been having several issues with my Firebase scheduled function.  I'm reviewing the logs and documentation and it's running and logs as "Success" and OK, but the desired nodes of my Realtime Database are not updating/deleting.  Here is my index.js code...

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  const ref = admin.database().ref('messages/{pushId}');
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
          return oldItemsQuery.once('value')
              .then(snapshot => {
                  // create a map with all children that need to be removed
                  var updates = {};
                  snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                      updates[child.key] = null
                  });
                  // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
                  return ref.update(updates);
              });
});
```

Here is how I've structured the data in my database reference that I want deleted at "cutoff"...

[image]

I've updated my firebase functions to the latest version.  The only other issue that may be causing this is a Warning that I should

> Consider adding ".indexOn": "timeStamp" at /messages/{pushId} to your
> security rules for better performance.

Since this was a warning and the function worked fine when it was .onWrite I'm not sure this is it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('messages/{pushId}');
```

The `{pushId}` in there makes no sense, and is causing you to query the wrong node.

You'll want to query and update:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('messages');
```